# Excel OCX ActiveX to view Excel

Tags: c#, .net, activex, ocx

Can you suggest me a way to display an Excel file within my .NET C# application? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://excelviewer.codeplex.com/) could be a good solution to your question.

Answer (score 1):

One option (your mileage may vary):

[How to use the WebBrowser control to open Office documents in Visual C# 2005 or in Visual C# .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304662)

[How to use the WebBrowser control to open an Office document](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/243058)